# How to properly validate attributes of custom directives?

Tags: angularjs, validation, angular-directive

Say I have a custom directive like this:

`<my-directive foo="ctrl.foo" bar="ctrl.bar"></my-directive>`

What would be the proper way to validate that both `foo` and `bar` attributes are valid? I mean, they are required for the directive to work, I don't mean type validation. What I need is to validate if the attribute is there because it's mandatory for this specific attribute (not sure if I should check if it's undefined or not, that maybe falls into type validation).

Is there any built-in way to achieve that or would I have to do it myself in the `link` function? A better question could be, does it make sense to even do that or should I just guarantee that my app is working with unit testing the specific controller that's passing the value to the directive? But what happens when the attribute value is static and doesn't come from the controller's scope?

Thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

If all you need is to make sure that attribute is not optional and it refers to valid variable on the scope, then consider (again - if you dismissed that idea) using these attributes with isolate scope's `=`.

So you could specify the required scope variables with:

```
scope: { requiredVar: '=requiredAttribute' },
scopeRequired: [ 'requiredVar' ],
```

`link` is a good place to modify the behaviour, because it concerns scope, and (if it is nested inside `compile`) it could get the reference to `this.scopeRequired` from it.

Sure, you could do this on per-directive basis, but if you want it as global behaviour... Here's the recipe I'm using to break into directives.

```
app.config(['$injector', function ($injector) {
  var _get = $injector.get;

  $injector.get = function patchedGet() {
    var provider = _get.apply(this, arguments);

    var providerName = arguments[0];
    var directiveName = (providerName.match(/(.+)DirectiveProvider$/) || [])[1];
    if (directiveName) {
      var _$get = provider.$get;
      console.log(['hi from injector get', arguments[0], provider.$get]);

      provider.$get = function patched$Get() {
        var instances = _$get.apply(this, arguments);
        console.log(['hi from provider $get', providerName, instances]);

        angular.forEach(instances, function(instance) {

          function getPatchedPostlink (postlink) {
            return function patchedPostlink(scope, element, attrs, ctrls) {
              var _postlink = postlink;
              console.log(['hi from directive link', directiveName, scope, element, attrs, ctrls]);

              // here it goes
              if (scope.$$isolateBindings && instance.scopeRequired) {
                var bindings = scope.$$isolateBindings;
                angular.forEach(instance.scopeRequired, function (scopeVar) {
                  if (!bindings[scopeVar] || !attrs.hasOwnProperty(bindings[scopeVar].attrName)) {
                    throw new Error("Scope variable '" + scopeVar + "', required by directive '" + directiveName + "', wasn't assigned!");
                  }
                });
              }

              return angular.isFunction(_postlink) ? _postlink.apply(this, arguments) : undefined;
            };
          }

          var _compile = instance.compile;

          // 'link' is impotent if there is 'compile'
          if (_compile) {
            instance.compile = function patchedCompile(element, attrs) {
              var compile = _compile.apply(instance, arguments);
              console.log(['hi from directive compile', directiveName, this, element, attrs]);

              if (!compile) {
                compile = {};
              } else if (angular.isFunction(compile)) {
                compile = { post: compile };
              }
              // compile.pre = getPatchedPrelink(compile.pre);
              compile.post = getPatchedPostlink(compile.post);
              return compile;
            };
          } else {
            instance.link = getPatchedPostlink(instance.link);
          }
        }, this); 
        return instances;
      };
    }
    return provider;
  };
}]);
```

Comment: I do that already but will that throw an error if I use my directive just like `<my-directive foo="ctrl.foo"></my-directive>` when `bar` is required and is defined as isolate scope's `=`? I actually didn't test this myself...

Comment: My bad, I didn't read the question carefully. Nope, it won't throw it, it will throw an error if you try to assign invalid scope variable. I've updated the answer, hope it helps.

Comment: Now that's an interesting solution :)

Comment: It is verbose but works fine for monkey-patching user-defined (but not ng) directives.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no any inbuilt validation available for attributes. You have to do it on your own. A cleaner approach is to throw an exception when the value in one of the required attribute is undefined on not valid.

Another way can be to simply return in case of required data is not found as throwing an exception may cause other problems.

Also, never assume that your controller or app is always going to pass valid data in the attributes so you can add those checks to make your code bullet proof.